# fetch php method comments

Tags: php, comments, methods

I want to fetch a method's comments,take below method for example:

```
/**
* Returns the regex to extract all inputs from a file.
* @param string The class name to search for.
* @return string The regex.
*/
public function method($param)
{
  //...
}
```

the result should be

```
Returns the regex to extract all inputs from a file.
@param string The class name to search for.
@return string The regex.
```

the way I find is use a function like file_get_content to get file content -> filter the method I want -> fetch the comment use regexp

it seems a bit complicated , is there any convenient way to archive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the comment in PHP for something check out `getDocComment` in php's [reflection api](http://php.net/reflection)

Comment: after a deep look , it isn't what I need . getDocComment just fetch class's comment , not method's. so I write a small script to do this http://gist.github.com/329113

Answer (score 6):

actually you can get a method's doc comments with getDocComment

```
$ref=new ReflectionMethod('className', 'methodName');

echo $ref->getDocComment();
```

Comment: This is correct, however it would be nice if you have mentioned that doc comment should be wrapped in `/** */` to be retrieved and then if there are multiple comments on a method only closest comment will be returned and also the returned string contains the comment stars too and a link to [ReflectionClass::getDocComment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php) for further reading.

Comment: Also note that, at the time of asking this question method you have mentioned wasn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Doc. Like Java Doc.

Answer (score 0):

For a method dump I use this little function I composed.
It fetches all methods from provided class that are public(and thus of use to you).

I personally use a dump() method to nicely format the outputted array of method names and descriptions, but that's not needed if you wish to use it for something else :-)

```
function getDocumentation($inspectclass) {
    /** Get a list of all methods */
    $methods = get_class_methods($inspectclass);
    /** Get the class name */
    $class =get_class($inspectclass);
    $arr = [];
    foreach($methods as $method) {
        $ref=new ReflectionMethod( $class, $method);
        /** No use getting private methods */
        if($ref->isPublic()) {
            $arr[$method] = $ref->getDocComment();
        }
    }
    /** dump is a formatting function I use, feel free to use your own */
    return dump($arr);
}
echo getDocumentation($this);
```